# Distinguishing record type from notification sent by iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm having issues distinguishing what type of record had a create, update, or delete.

I have two `CKSubscription`s for different types of records; Dog and Cat.

From looking at the `[String : AnyObject]`, there isn't any way of distinguishing whether something happened to a Dog or Cat.

Something like this is sent to the app as a remote notification.

```
["ck": {
    ce = 2;
    cid = "iCloud.com.xxx.yyy";
    nid = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
    qry =     {
        dbs = 2; // I don't know what this is, but it doesn't change
        fo = 3; // This indicates a deletion. 
        rid = "SomeManuallySetID";
        sid = "117DCFC3-F723-49F7-9F9D-A3D7463671F2";
        zid = "_defaultZone";
        zoid = "_defaultOwner";
    };
}]
```

Has anyone been able to do so without doing a query to iCloud again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first get a `CKNotification` from the `NSNotification`. Then after determining it is a query notification you convert it to a `CKQueryNotification`. From that you can get the `CKRecordID`. Using that you can fetch the `CKRecord` from the `CKDatabase`. Once you have the `CKRecord` you can use the `recordType` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Most of the knowledge I have are based on blog posts, and they didn't mention anything about CKQueryNotification. Thanks, I will look into this class via the official documents. Oh, but you do need to fetch it yourself then.

Comment: You can specify fields of the record to include in the push notification’s payload data through `notificationInfo`. This may help you differentiate, depending on your circumstances.